# Armazenamento em arquivo binário

Tags: c, arquivo, struct

No programa, preciso implementar uma estrutura que represente um aluno (nome, idade e matrícula). Utilizando essa estrutura, tenho que escrever um programa que leia os dados de 5 alunos e os armazene em um arquivo binário.

Implementei a estrutura da seguinte maneira:

```
typedef struct
{
    char nome[50];
    int idade;
    int matricula;
} aluno;
```

Na função principal, fiz da seguinte maneira:

```
int main(int args, char *arg[])
{
    FILE *arq;
    arq = fopen("registro.txt", "wb");
    if(arq == NULL)
    {
        printf("Erro ao criar o arquivo");
        exit(1);
    }

    aluno registro[5];
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        gets(registro[i].nome);
        scanf("%d %d", &registro[i].idade, &registro[i].matricula);
        fprintf(arq, "%s | %d | %d\n", registro[i].nome, registro[i].idade, 
registro[i].matricula);
    }

    fclose(arq);
    return 0;
}
```

O programa foi compilado sem nenhum erro, mas quando vou digitar as informações do aluno, só consigo ler a informação de 3 alunos, e não de 5 alunos como o exercício pede. Gostaria de saber porque está acontecendo isso e também gostaria de saber se esse método de armazenar em um arquivo binário está correto.

Answer (score 2):

Você está abrindo o arquivo em modo binário para gravação (`wb`), mas não está gravando o conteúdo de forma correta...

A gravação e a leitura dos dados devem ser feitas com as funções `fwrite()` e `fread()` respectivamente.

Segue um código (testado) exemplificando a solução do problema:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct aluno_s
{
    char nome[50];
    int idade;
    int matricula;
} aluno_t;


size_t gravar_registro( FILE * pf, char * nome, int idade, int mat )
{
    aluno_t a;

    strcpy( a.nome, nome );
    a.idade = idade;
    a.matricula = mat;

    return fwrite( &a, sizeof(aluno_t), 1, pf );
}


void ler_registro( FILE * pf, int mat )
{
    aluno_t a;

    while( fread( &a, sizeof(aluno_t), 1, pf ) )
    {
        if( a.matricula == mat )
        {
            printf( "Nome     : %s\n", a.nome );
            printf( "Idade    : %d\n", a.idade );
            printf( "Matricula: %d\n", a.matricula );
            printf( "\n" );

            break;
        }
    }
}


int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    FILE * arq = NULL;

    /* Abre arquivo para gravacao em modo binario... */
    arq = fopen( "registro.bin", "wb");

    if( !arq )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Erro ao abrir arquivo para gravacao.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Cadastra 5 alunos... */
    gravar_registro( arq, "Albert Einstein", 65, 1234 );
    gravar_registro( arq, "Isaac Newton",    43, 3579 );
    gravar_registro( arq, "Galileu Galilei", 80, 2468 );
    gravar_registro( arq, "Michael Faraday", 77, 1000 );
    gravar_registro( arq, "James Maxwell",   43, 5050 );

    /* Fecha arquivo...*/
    fclose(arq);

    /* Abre arquivo para leitura em modo binario... */
    arq = fopen( "registro.bin", "rb");

    if( !arq )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Erro ao abrir arquivo para leitura.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Faz a leitura dos alunos pelo codigo de matricula  */
    ler_registro( arq, 1234 );
    ler_registro( arq, 3579 );
    ler_registro( arq, 2468 );
    ler_registro( arq, 1000 );
    ler_registro( arq, 5050 );

    /* Fecha arquivo...*/
    fclose(arq);

    /* Sucesso */
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Saída:

```
$ ./cadastro
Nome     : Albert Einstein
Idade    : 65
Matricula: 1234

Nome     : Isaac Newton
Idade    : 43
Matricula: 3579

Nome     : Galileu Galilei
Idade    : 80
Matricula: 2468

Nome     : Michael Faraday
Idade    : 77
Matricula: 1000

Nome     : James Maxwell
Idade    : 43
Matricula: 5050
```

Comment: Valeu pela resposta Lacobus! Mas tenho uma dúvida. Você usou size_t. Qual é a finalidade dele?